# Linq to Entities: Updating a Field in a Custom Class

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-entities

I’m using Linq to Entities with an Oracle database. I’m trying to update (just for showing, no to update the database) the result query… is easy for me if I show you what I’m doing:

```
Public Function getValues(ID As String) As IQueryable(Of  CUSTOM_CLASS)

     Dim theValues = db.SOMETABLE _
                       .Where(Function(st) st.ID = ID) _ 
                       .Select(Function(st) New CUSTOM_CLASS With{ _
                            .ID          = st.ID, _
                            .DESCRIPTION = st.DESCRIPTION, _
                            .CUSTOM_FIELD = “”
                       })

    For Each v in theValues
         v.CUSTOM_FIELD = functionThatReturnSomeValue()
    Next 

    Return theValues

End Function
```

My code compiles without problems, and if I debug, CUSTOM_FIELD has “Some Value” as the value. But when I use this function, I get the result WITHOUT the values in CUSTOM_FIELD.
What I’m doing wrong?

Thanks!

Edgar.

Comment: What do you see in the debugger in v.CUSTOM_FIELD right after the assignment?

Comment: Not sure why it is not working. Does forcing execution of the query (e.g. by adding a call to ToList()) before your For loop make a difference?

Comment: No, I got the same result

Comment: Perhaps the query is getting executed again, overwriting your CUSTOM_FIELD value. Try changing the return type of this function to List rather than IQueryable.

Comment: I still think your query is getting re-executed somehow. This works for me only iff I have the ToList() call in there:
static string fff()
{
return "xtz";
}
public class XY
{
public string Name;
public string X;
}
void Main()
{

 var x= MyEntitySet.Select(yy => new XY {Name = yy.Name, X = "" }).ToList();
 x.Dump();
 foreach (var y in x)
 {
  y.X = fff();
 }
 x.Dump();
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think your query is getting re-executed somehow. This works for me only iff I have the ToList() call in there (tested in LINQPad):

```
public class XY
{
  public string Name;
  public string X;
}
void Main()
{

    var x= MyEntitySet.Select(yy => new XY {Name = yy.Name, X = "" }).ToList();
    x.Dump();
    foreach (var y in x)
    {
        y.X = "someText";
    }
    x.Dump();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Craig!! After all, the trick was using .ToList() as you suggested from the beginning. The thing is I put it on the for as this:

For Each v in theValues.ToList()

That doesn't work, then I move it to the end of the orginal query and it works!